# Nested query not working in Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0, nosql

```
USE users_tracking;
SELECT user_name FROM visits
where port_name IN 
(SELECT port_name FROM ports where location = 'NY' )//as temp;
```

It gives an error 
`mismatched input 'SELECT' expecting RULE_T_R_PAREN`

Is there any way I can store the inner query in a variable and then use that?
I tried using `set@varname := query` but  it does not recognize the set command.

Answer (score 14):

Nested queries are not allowed in Cassandra CQL. For this kind of complex querying feature you'll need to use Hive or SparkSQL.

Here is a full CQL reference,
http://cassandra.apache.org/doc/cql3/CQL.html